# how to filter with reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, jsx

im using React in my app i have table i want to filter the gender by Male or Female. I want to a filter for the gender so I can search the employees by their genders if it is possible to do.

+++++ IM TOTALY NEW TO PROGRAMMING

```
export default class EmployeeList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employees: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.employeesTracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      Meteor.subscribe('employees');
      const employees = Employees.find().fetch();
      this.setState({ employees });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.employeesTracker.stop();
  }

  renderEmployeesListItems() {
    return this.state.employees.map(employee => {
      return (
        <tr key={employee._id}>
          <td>{employee.name}</td>
          <td>{employee.email}</td>
          <td>{employee.age}</td>
          <td>{employee.gender}</td>
          <td>{employee.city}</td>
          <td><Link className="link button" to={`/employee-detail/${employee._id}`}>EDIT</Link></td>
          <td><button className="button pointer" onClick={() => Employees.remove({_id: employee._id})}>DELETE</button></td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="employeeTable">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
            <th>AGE</th>
            <th>GENDER</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
            {this.renderEmployeesListItems()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One problem you will find is that something that contains the text FEMALE also contains the text MALE.

Comment: ```input = document.getElementById("mylist");``` is returning null.  Seems like dom not found because id parameter does not match. Can you verify it is mylist or myList or may be something else or may be you call a function before dom attach.

Comment: seems weird to be referencing DOM in react

Comment: `myFunction(e) { const filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase` That would get you your filter. I would not use getElementById in react components. Just filter the sate using setState and use state to generate the table.

Comment: @HMR sorry I didn't get it. plus im noob in react but trying to learn :(

Comment: antho's given answer pretty much uses component state to hold the filter data and props to hold the data. A react component can have state and/or have props. Usually props are passed from a parent component or selected from application state through a container for example connect of [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should use React workflow

```
function RenderEmployees(props: Employee[]) {

    const [sexe, setSexe] = useState('male');
    renderEmployeesListItems = () => {
       props.filter((employee: Employee)=> employee.sexe === sexe)
       .map((employee)=>
         <tr>
            <td>{employee.name}</td>
            <td>{employee.email}</td>
            <td>{employee.age}</td>
            <td>{employee.gender}</td> // who egal with sexe
            <td>{employee.city}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                 <h2>Filter</h2>
                 <button onClick={setSexe('male')}>
                      Male
                 </button>
                 <button onClick={setSexe('female')}>
                      Female
                </button>
            </div>
            <table className="employeeTable" id="myTable">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>EMAIL</th>
                <th>AGE</th>
                <th>GENDER</th>
                <th>CITY</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
                    {renderEmployeesListItems()}
            </tbody>
            </table>      
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. if you don't mind look at my whole page without me adding the -myFunction- and the Radio button. how can I fix it from here. Again thank you for your answer.

Comment: You need to stock your filter state and `employeesTracker`

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean by "stock your filter state and employeesTracker". can you explain more or edit your answer?

Comment: Please antho can you explain more or edit your answer Please I need your help

Comment: React workflow is as follow => each component get a state value, this value is to store informations about componenet it's like self configurations, the other value is props, it's extra information come from parent, in your case it's Employees list

Comment: In your case `employeesTracker` need to be in your state variable
Same for your filter cause when you are render your componenet filter value will change and you render too

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand becuase my english is bad. Thank you for your time